# Random horizontal white stripe in exported PNG (Illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, png

I have designed a shape in Illustrator and I'm exporting this to PNG, however, some random, white line appears in the exported PNG.

I've tried exporting it to different formats (BMP, PDF) and no other file format exports it with a white line. I have shut off all layers, so it's only the bottom layer that's visible in the file, no other extra layers.

**Illustrator**
[image]

**PNG**
[image]

**BMP**
[image]

**PNG purple** (to show it doesn't matter which color I choose)
[image]

Now, it's going to be an icon in the end, so it will probably disappear, but it's really weird to me where this horizontal line is coming from. Does anyone have an idea? It shows up at the same spot every single time, but it's random since it shows up without reason.

EDIT: When I open a PNG file in Photoshop, it actually shows it's a **transparent** line, not white!

[image]

[Download the test file here](http://xtra.billetten.dk/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/test.ai)

Comment: is there, possibly, a division between two adjacent objects there? It's possible that Ai's png renderer anti-aliases both shapes separately.

Comment: The background shape is one, made with a solid square in the beginning. The half-circles on the right have been added later, but they have no overlap with the original square. I have made the file available with a link in the bottom of my question if you want to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this result.What I did was

Go to File>Export>Select File type>Resolution 300ppi>Anti aliasing(supersampling),tick mark antialiasing,background color transparent> Ok

[image]

Comment: When I use your settings, it doesn't show the line, when I use mine (Type Optimized (hinted) and no check mark at Interlaced) it directly shows. So, we have found what FIXES it, but what is the REASON why it happens?

Comment: That doesn't really explain why I get a transparent, horizontal line. But thanks anyway!